# How do you set stack size with a call to boost::process::launch()?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, process, stack

In my mac development, I am using boost::process::launch() where it's failing since my soft limit is 8192kb. Setting it to 65532 would resolve my issue (ulimit -s 65532). How do I set this soft stack size when calling boost::process::launch() on a unix-based machine?

Comment: you don't, and it would be platform specific anyways. So, better figure out how to do it on your platform and optionally suggest a feature at the Boost Process devs

Comment: How would I use it with the posix_spawn call? I am not seeing any attributes or such to modify.

Comment: Sorry. How would you use >what<? I don't see any code. I have actually written extensions to Boost Process (and [it's not that hard](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_process/extend.html)) so we would be able to do anything, IFF you showed what you want to do